# Storing private key on web server

Tags: c#, cryptography

In my current project, I am working on a SAML implementation where the "payload" is encrypted.

The identity provider is being given our public key and we then use your private key to decrypt.

My questions is on how I should protect my private key on the server.

The public-facing website is set up in a DMZ and the web services are behind a firewall on a physically different server. Communication is done via WCF.

I would like to take advantage of having separate servers so that I don't have to place the .pfx file on the web server where it could be accessed. However, I don't feel comfortable simply placing the .pfx file on the web services file system.

Does it make more sense to access the private key from the "certificate store"? Is there a way to embed the contents of the pfx file into the binary of my app?

Appreciate any input!

Comment: This might be better suited for security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is it possible to move the question over to security.SE or do I need to open a new one there?

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means a security guru so take what I say with a grain of salt. But could you encrypt your pfx file with a symmetric algorithm such as XXTEA, or blowfish? Then just decrypt it before you need it? That would offer reasonable security and allow you to place it on the Web servers file system. This is just an idea, I'm sure someone with more knowledge will be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: Where would you place the symmetric key? And you cannot decrypt using a wrapped key (as it is called) either.

Comment: Good point I hadn't really thought of that. He mentioned embedding the pfx file in his app somehow. So I just assumed that his app works with the pfx file. So he could write the decrypt routine into the app itself. With a hard coded symmetric key. But I'm unsure of his exact requirements so that might not work either.